# How To Set Up Table In Modal View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a TableView, when you click add + button in nav bar, it brings up a modal view that will have another separate table in it which will have subviews etc.

So far, I have the tableViewController and the model view is in there as a UIView.  My question is, how do I setup the tableViews that go in the modal view?  Do I make new classes for the rootview and subviews etc?  Should I switch the modal view to its own class also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the modal view in a Modal View Controller and do a presentModalViewControllerAnimated to show it.

The modal view controller is a UIViewController subclass and in that class you can manage all the stuff you want to do in your modal view.

Comment: Ok, So I can create a testModalViewController class and do everything the same as it was a normal tableviewcontroller, etc.  Then in my original viewController I can set presentModalViewControllerAnimated as a target to an add button?

Comment: so I have this method `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated`.  How do I tell it which class is the modalview I want?

Comment: I actually found some good info in the Apple Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1